# Postgres query that ignores the first 2 entries of day per group

Tags: postgresql

I want to make a postgres select query that ignores the first 2 entries of day per queue, where a "day" is defined as starting at 18:00

For example, If my data is like:

| id | queue | timestamp (bigint) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | q1 | 1673721000000000000 (2023-01-14 18:30:00) - first entry of day for q1 |
| 2 | q1 | 1673728200000000000 (2023-01-14 20:30:00) |
| 3 | q1 | 1673760600000000000 (2023-01-15 05:30:00) |
| 4 | q1 | 1673806000000000000 (2023-01-15 18:10:00) - first entry of day for q1 |
| 5 | q2 | 1673721000000000000 (2023-01-14 18:30:00) - first entry of day for q2 |
| 6 | q2 | 1673728200000000000 (2023-01-14 20:30:00) |
| 7 | q2 | 1673760600000000000 (2023-01-15 05:30:00) |
| 8 | q2 | 1673802600000000000 (2023-01-15 17:10:00) |
| 9 | q2 | 1674067800000000000 (2023-01-18 18:50:00) - first entry of day for q2 |
| 10 | q2 | 1674075000000000000 (2023-01-18 20:50:00) |
| 11 | q2 | 1674096600000000000 (2023-01-19 02:50:00) |
| 12 | q2 | 1674132600000000000 (2023-01-19 12:50:00) |
| 13 | q3 | 1673721000000000000 (2023-01-14 18:30:00) - first entry of day for q3 |
| 14 | q3 | 1673728200000000000 (2023-01-14 20:30:00) |

The select results should be ids 3 7 8 11 and 12:

| id | queue | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | q1 | 1673760600000000000 |
| 7 | q2 | 1673760600000000000 |
| 8 | q2 | 1673802600000000000 |
| 11 | q2 | 1674096600000000000 |
| 12 | q2 | 1674132600000000000 |

I've tried using select row_number over a partition, but having issues getting the filtering correct.

// of course this doesn't work, since it only ignores first 2 of all time, not per day starting at 18:00

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT row_number() over (PARTITION by queue ORDER by timestamp) as row_n,
                                                                      *
  FROM mytable
) results
WHERE results.row_n > 2
```

// gives hourly time of timestamp

```
CAST((to_timestamp("timestamp"/1000000000)) AS time)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please simplify the question to focus on the problem. Use a proper `timestamp` data type (not a `bigint`)

Comment: Avoid using keywords and builtin functions as column names; e.g., `timestamp` is a keyword in PostgreSQL and SQL and is also reserved in SQL. Identifiers should be named according to business use, not the type. In this case, _timestamp_ might be better named _entry_time_ns_ to reflect that the column holds the queue entry time as a nanosecond value. Beware of potential time zone issues when translating this column value to a timestamp.

Comment: @JohnH i replaced the actual column names in my question, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ts` is your `timestamp`you should *partition* on the following expression

```
 partition by queue, (ts - interval'18' hour)::date
```

Note that you subtract the 18 hours (for the day start) and cast to `date` to get a single value.

**Sample Query**

To get the *row_number*  of the first and second row per day starting at 18 hour. (leaving the rest out as not important)

```
with dt as (
select 'q1' queue, date'2023-01-01' + n * interval '3' hour ts from generate_series(1,20) t(n) union all
select 'q2' queue, date'2023-01-01' + n * interval '5' hour ts from generate_series(1,20) t(n)
)
select 
  queue, ts,
  row_number() over (partition by queue, (ts - interval'18' hour)::date  order by ts) as rn,
  (ts - interval'18' hour)::date 
from dt 

queue|ts                 |rn|date      |
-----+-------------------+--+----------+
q1   |2023-01-01 03:00:00| 1|2022-12-31|
q1   |2023-01-01 06:00:00| 2|2022-12-31|
q1   |2023-01-01 09:00:00| 3|2022-12-31|
...
q1   |2023-01-01 18:00:00| 1|2023-01-01|
q1   |2023-01-01 21:00:00| 2|2023-01-01|
q1   |2023-01-02 00:00:00| 3|2023-01-01|
...
q2   |2023-01-01 05:00:00| 1|2022-12-31|
q2   |2023-01-01 10:00:00| 2|2022-12-31|
q2   |2023-01-01 15:00:00| 3|2022-12-31|
q2   |2023-01-01 20:00:00| 1|2023-01-01|
q2   |2023-01-02 01:00:00| 2|2023-01-01|
q2   |2023-01-02 06:00:00| 3|2023-01-01|
...
q2   |2023-01-02 21:00:00| 1|2023-01-02|
q2   |2023-01-03 02:00:00| 2|2023-01-02|
q2   |2023-01-03 07:00:00| 3|2023-01-02|
...
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I was able to create the query I needed using this.
Thanks a lot!